# issue with agrep

Tags: r, agrep

why does agrep find a match although I restrict max.distance to zero?
adist does correctly tell me that I need two insertations...

```
> agrep("ab", "abcd", max = list(del = 0, ins = 0, sub = 0), value = T)
[1] "abcd"
> drop(attr(adist("ab", "abcd", counts = TRUE), "counts"))
ins del sub 
  2   0   0 

> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] formatR_0.6   vegan_2.0-4   permute_0.7-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1    lattice_0.20-6 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: The Note section in `?agrep` would seem to apply to you here.

Comment: @joran I read the note but can't see why it should apply here..

Comment: The key phrase is that `agrep` matches the pattern **within** each string in x, not to the whole string. Subtle (which is probably why they added the note).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that "ab" matches perfectly (no insertions needed!) with the first two characters of "abcd".  That is what the Note section that @joran referenced is telling you.

```
# Since ab matches the substring of abcd that is the first two characters
# we get a match
agrep("ab", "abcd", val = T)
#[1] "abcd"

# Since we only need 1 insertion to make ac into abc and we set max=1
# we get a match
agrep("ac", "abcd", max = 1, val = T)
#[1] "abcd"

# ac doesn't directly match any part of the substring and we set max=0
# so no match
agrep("ac", "abcd", max = 0, val = T)
#character(0)
```

Comment: +1 - nice explanation. `agrep` has always been a bit of a mysterious creature to me.

Comment: I already explained why you're getting the result you're getting (it's by design).  If you want something else you could just use `adist`.  But really it sounds like you're looking for exact matches in which case `agrep` and `adist` really aren't the functions you should be using...

Comment: @dason, I deleted my comment. You're explanation was clear. However, I'm rather unhappy with the design of agrep (matching of substrings). i.e. I dislike the fact that you get different results in `agrep("abcd", "ab")` and `agrep("ab", "abcd")`..

Comment: You're allowed to be unhappy with it but that doesn't change the design.  I personally think it makes a lot of sense.  Say I have a bunch of sentences (each sentence being a string in a character vector) I need to look through and want to scan for "Dason" but I'm afraid some people have done some entry errors so I want to look for things that might be close to Dason as well.  `agrep` makes this task relatively easy.  Personally it just sounds like you should be using `adist` directly.